# Laravel 5.1 How to translate attribute values in the form validation messages?

Tags: php, forms, validation, laravel, laravel-5.1

I need to translate the attribute values for the form validations. So I have duplicated the English validation errors and translated them to Farsi. Everything works but the attribute values are still in English. I thought I need to put the translation of attributes in the attributes array in the validation file as follows, but it's not working.

```
'attributes' => [
        'username '=>'نام کاربری'
    ],
```

How can I translate them?

Comment: It seem that attribute names do not exist, therefore your application returns the attribute name from fall-back's language file.

Comment: @manix I'm pretty sure it exists!

Comment: I didn't get you. You want to change the validation message, right? for example message of required field. And how do you validate your request inputs? Through Request class or by validate function?

Comment: @manix I found the problem.  As it can be seen in the question there is a space after the attribute name which makes the attribute nonexistent.

Comment: @Ali No I just needed to translate the attributes inside validation messages.

Comment: @AliErfani, I told you! the key did not exist LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a space after username before the quote so the attribute key is different. Remove the space so that it is the same.